# Is already there a fix to the OxygenOS issue with the BiometricPrompt?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, oneplus6t, oneplus7

I understand that until version 9 of Oxygen this error occurred:

[Biometric Prompt issue on Oneplus 6T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcOyY.png)

I'm Filtering devices with in-display fingerprint sensor, so I can give a specific behaviour:

```
//OnePlus models without in-display biometric sensor
private static final String[] onePlusModelsWithoutBiometricBug = {
        "A0001", // OnePlus One
        "ONE A2001", "ONE A2003", "ONE A2005", // OnePlus 2
        "ONE E1001", "ONE E1003", "ONE E1005", // OnePlus X
        "ONEPLUS A3000", "ONEPLUS SM-A3000", "ONEPLUS A3003", // OnePlus 3
        "ONEPLUS A3010", // OnePlus 3T
        "ONEPLUS A5000", // OnePlus 5
        "ONEPLUS A5010", // OnePlus 5T
        "ONEPLUS A6000", "ONEPLUS A6003", // OnePlus 6
        "ONEPLUS BE2029", "ONEPLUS BE2025", "ONEPLUS BE2026", "ONEPLUS BE2028", // Nord N10
        "ONEPLUS BE2013", "ONEPLUS BE2015", "ONEPLUS BE2011", "ONEPLUS BE2012", // Nord N100
        "ONEPLUS DE2118", "ONEPLUS DE2117", // Nord N200
};

public static boolean hasOnePlusBiometricBug() {
    return Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("oneplus") &&
            !Arrays.asList(onePlusModelsWithoutBiometricBug).contains(Build.MODEL);
                //&& Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q; //ToDo: verify this
}
```

I don't have a OnePlus phone to test it myself. So I just want to know if this problem is fixed or not and from what version of OxygenOS if yes.